# Fibonacci in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I was reading a book, where the author said, with no proof, that

> No four distinct fibonacci numbers are in arithmetic progression.

I tried with no progress for about one hour.

Can anyone show me a proof, please?

Comment: No proof in that link too.

Comment: Interesting link @lab bhattacharjee but unfortunately the proof is missing

Comment: I have found a proof. What should I do now?

Comment: @MuhammadRaselParvej I would be interested in seeing the proof; I believe you can answer your own question?

Comment: Yes answer your own question

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume $F_h < F_i < F_j < F_k$ are in AP, so $F_i — F_h = F_k — F_j=d$, the common difference

Then $d = F_i-F_h < F_i$; on the other hand, $d = F_k-F_j \geq F_k-F_{k-1}=F_{k-2}\geq F_i$, which poses a contradiction.

Comment: $F_{k-2}\geq F_i$ implies $d\geq F_i$. Isn't it a contradiction to $d<F_i$?

Comment: Why would $F_k-F_j \geq F_k-F_{k-1}$ imply that there is an extra fibonacci number between $F_k$ and $F_{k-1}$?

Comment: No, it's okay. Minus changes the direction of the inequality.